# Is there any alternate for animating array of images using UIImageView?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

`UIImageView` has `animationImages` for animating sequence of images. That works fine. But It holds the images object. So There is a spike in use of memory when this animation is happening. I tried `NSTimer` for setting image property of that image view, But it doesn't work.

Can we achieve this in any other approach?

Comment: You can draw images one after another using CoreGraphics and CADisplayLink.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for alternatives, just try to correct the existing code.

The best practice of allocating an image for `animationImages` should be using `initWithContentsOfFile` instead of `imageNamed:`

`imageNamed:` it cache’s your images and you lose control over the memory - there's no guarantee that releasing the object will actually release the image but does provide faster loading of images second time around as they are cached.

`imageWithContentsOfFile:` it does not cache images and is more memory friendly however as it does not cache images and the heavier images are loaded much slower.

When the animation does stop, just release the image collection array. If you are using ARC then make it the image collection array to nil.

**Best Practice:**

```
for(int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < 20; itemIndex++) {
   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage1" ofType:@"png"];
   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

   [imageArray addObject:image];
}
```

**After the Animation:**

```
imageArray = nil;
```